# Force a specific logger in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, logback, pact

We wanted to switch from standard logback to log4j in Spring Boot 2.4.x.
For most modules, it is a no-brainer by simply removing the dependency of logback, but there are some modules, which are using pact-jvm as a shadow-jar dependency to be able to create the pact files from unit tests.

Now the odyssey begins, because pact needs logback and with the pact-jar on the classpath Spring recognizes the logback class it is looking for and decides to use logback instead of log4j as the logger in the tests.

Is there a possibility to create something like a log bean or a hidden configuration, which allows forcing Spring to use log4j instead of logback, also if logback is on the classpath?

Pact should not be an issue at this point, because the server is started as a standalone server from gradle. We only require the dependency to be able to start everything and to have the classes available.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're basically describing log4j-over-slf4j. It acts as a bridge for everything which uses log4j directly to slf4j, then slf4j uses your logging framework of choice. See also http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps to configure log4j with spring boot

1. Add the log4j dependency to your module
2. Create logger object in your respective class and use the logger object to log the messages.

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(<YourClassName>.class);
```

3. In your spring boot module/project add log4j.properties file in resources so that this will be available on class path at runtime. Following is sample content for the log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**Make sure that the spring boot module bundles the log4j jar when you build.**

Once spring boot finds the log4j jar and the log4j.properties on the class path it will be able to initialize the log4j logger for you.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. The issue is, that Spring Boots Autoconfiguration is loading the logger for slf4j (sorry forgot that). So here it iterates over the supported candidates in the order:

Comment: Do you get any error stack? Will it be possible to share your code where we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, because of the short comments, I rewrote my comment as an answer below.
In general the stacktrace says, there is no proper logback(-spring).xml (because I set config to log4j2.xml). But that's only the result of the way how Spring is choosing the logger.
In my case, I don't want to have Spring logger selection magic with reflections based on the availability of a class here. I just want to force Spring to use log4j, also if logback is maybe on the classpath.
It's a bit strange to me, that most things are configurable with beans, but not the logger (as far I can see).

Comment: Other way could be to exclude the logger dependency from spring boot
https://ichihedge.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/disable-logback-enable-log4j2slf4j-in-spring-boot/

Comment: That's what I've done, but like I described, the Pact Server forces logback and if I exclude everything, Pact fails, which does not allow me to execute the tests.
The application itself has no logback inside. I only do have the problem with the tests, which have the dependency to Pact JVM Server.

Comment: A sample code will be helpful to understand how your configurations are and can be tried build and run locally to see the issue in detail. Please share any public repository code base in case you have one

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's clear. The issue is, that Spring Boots Autoconfiguration is loading the logger for slf4j (sorry forgot that). So here it iterates over the supported candidates in the order:

- logback
- log4j
- apache-log-commons

And it seems that it does not look for beans, it simply looks for the classes by reflection.

If we now start the app for testing together with pact server, Spring Boot resolves an Append* class and thinks, that this has to be the logger of our choice.
It creates the logback instance, which is searching for its config, but then it fails, because the config is for log4j.